# Get position of mysqlbinlog error. I have the error's line number

Tags: mysql, replication, mysqlbinlog

If I use mysqlbinlog to load a binlog into my database like this:

```
mysqlbinlog --defaults-file=/path/mysqld.cnf bin.000011| mysql -u root
```

and get an error like this:

```
ERROR 2006 at line 290: MySQL server has gone away
```

How do I convert line 290 into a binlog position that I can use to rerun the log, starting at the failed line?

```
 mysqlbinlog --defaults-file=/path/mysqld.cnf --start-position=<WANT THIS> bin.000011| mysql -u root
```

I'm using binlog-format=ROW

Or, how can I log the binlog position of the error, and not just the line number?

It seems that there must be a way to recover from an error while updating a database with mysqlbinlog, otherwise the whole database is corrupted.

Comment: [gone away error causes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this steps/workaround :

1. Take converted binary logs in separate file.

`mysqlbinlog --base64-output=DECODE-ROWS -v hostname_binlog.00XXX > Binary_log.sql`

2. You directly `Binary_log.sql` file on MySQL server or you can use `mysqlbinlog` command ( if you have sufficient space)

`mysqlbinlog --base64-output=DECODE-ROWS -v hostname_binlog.00XXX | mysql -v -u root`

Here using -v ( verbose ), logs will printed on terminal & you can get details of each statement.